# mysql query from python returning no results

Tags: python, mysql, sql

So I've already taken a look at the documentation and other questions but I've had no luck.

When I run c.execute and have the first %s, coded with the value, it works. Yet, if I try to allow that to be a variable, I get no results. From my understanding, I put use %s as a place holder and then pass a list of those variables as the second parameter. Am I missing something? The cursor from db_connect is conn.cursor(cursors.DictCursor) in this case because I want a dictionary of the results. Either way, I get nothing in a or b, but if I run the same query with "SELECT * FROM users where username = %s", then I get a result.

```
from MySQLdb import escape_string
from db_connect import connection
import gc

def get_user(parameter, value):
    c, conn = connection(dict_cursor = True)
    data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users where %s = %s",[escape_string(parameter), escape_string(value)])
    data = c.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    gc.collect()
    return data

a = get_user("username","testuser")
b = get_user("email","testuser@icloud.com")
c = get_user("username","doesntexist")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes.  You can replace constants in a query with parameters.  However, you cannot replace identifiers.  This includes:

- table names
- column names
- function names
- operators
- SQL keywords

What you can do is replace the column name with a string substitution and then pass the comparison value as a parameter.

Comment: In that case, can I do something like: data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users where "+parameter+"= %s",[escape_string(value)]) ? Is this secure since there's no escape_string or anything around it?

Comment: @GeorgeLingo . . . Alas, it is not secure.  Replacing identifiers in query strings is a security hole in parameterized SQL.